# Convert Data (object) into file format byte array

Tags: c#, file, format

I want to save some measured data into a file. For using the file in other application i had to bring the data in to an specific file format. I have a table with the following information:

- Offset
- Bytes
- Type
- Description

for each Element of the header.

So, i have to convert all the information of my object in this format. Is there a simple way to do that? Is is the right way to make a big byte array and fill this information into the array?

Comment: In what format? You have not provided a clear, precise, unambiguous specification of the desired format. It's doubtful you need to "make a big byte array", but without a clearly written question, no one can know for sure.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to convert your data and write to a file then just convert and write it. <strike>This is the simplest way</strike>. Example code:

```
struct Data
{
    int offset;
    byte[] bytes;
    byte type;
    string description;
}

void WriteDataToStream(Stream outputStream, List<Data> data)
{
    using(var bw = new BinaryWriter(outputStream))
    {
        foreach(var d in data)
        {
            bw.Write(d.offset);
            bw.Write(d.bytes, 0, d.bytes.Length);
            bw.Write(d.type);
            bw.Write(d.description);
        }
    }
}
```

The stream may be `FileStream`. Note that the `BinaryWriter` will close base stream at Dispose, but you can convert data explicitly and write to base stream as byte array by yourself.

---

Other way, you can implement `ISerealizable` interface. I think it will be simplest.